# LaTeX documents in Indian languages prepared using LaTeX

Tags: xetex, indic, hindi

We know that LaTeX supports Indian languages. I have seen some documents in Sanskrit which are typeset using LaTeX. However, I am curious if there are other examples of documents in Indic scripts which are typeset using LaTeX.

In this question, I would request you to post such examples. I shall start by citing three examples which I know:

1. Sanskrit Documents http://sanskritdocuments.org
   This is a well-known project and one can see that the documents are typeset in LaTeX --- using the velthuis package and the recent one seems to use polyglosia. However, I could not find any official or formal claim on the website that says so. Could anyone please confirm this guess?
2. I and some colleagues of mine undertook the project of typesetting some Marathi wikibooks using LaTeX. Our typesetting follows the traditional style with a modern touch. We have six such documents prepared now and made available under Creative Commons licences:
   https://sites.google.com/site/latexmrbooks/pustake-utarava
3. Prof. Zdednek Wagner has some books written in Hindi, or Hindi and Czech
   http://icebearsoft.euweb.cz/art.php

Now you are welcome to add to the list!

Comment: There is currently a thread on the xetex list of examples for Sanskrit and Devanagari, see
https://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2019-May/thread.html  (more a list of manuals than a list of example typeset books, so not posting as an answer)

Comment: Thank you! I, somehow, missed the thread.
I am wondering about (only in Devanagari or Sankrit) but other languages as well.